# Execute pytest in order

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

Hi I am checking out "http://pytest-ordering.readthedocs.org/en/develop/" to execute pytest in order

I tried the following code,

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.order2
def test_foo():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.order1
def test_bar():
    assert True
```

But still the execution is random. Can someone please let me know how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the project maintainer does not have much time to support the project anymore: [last update](https://github.com/ftobia/pytest-ordering/commits/develop) was 5 months ago and the [issue tracker](https://github.com/ftobia/pytest-ordering/issues) is filled with related opened issues. One of them is closely related to your problem:

- [pytest.mark.order1 doesn't work after updating from 0.3 to 0.4](https://github.com/ftobia/pytest-ordering/issues/19)

---

I've actually found that the `run(order=N)` works better but don't use negative indexing - they are [not going to work](https://github.com/ftobia/pytest-ordering/issues/21). The following works for me:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.run(order=3)
def test_three():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.run(order=4)
def test_four():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.run(order=2)
def test_two():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.run(order=1)
def test_one():
    assert True
```

Produces:

```
test.py::test_one PASSED
test.py::test_two PASSED
test.py::test_three PASSED
test.py::test_four PASSED
```

Comment: I have two test case files say test_sample1.py and test_sample2.py , In each file I use setup_class and teardown_class. Now if I use the ordering what ever may be the file but it picks up order1 in all test case file and execute it first. Is there way to avoid it?